# HTMLENTITIES delete words with accents

Tags: php, html-entities

In a script, I would like to recovery datas from database. When datas are displayed in the screen, characters  with accents are showed in a interrogation point. I tried to use 'HTMLENTITES($variable, ENT_HTML5) and words dispared from the screen. The script and datas are encoded in UTF8.

What do you do to display datas without interrogation point ?

Thanks for help in advance!

Here, the code.

```
$requete = "SELECT ID_MODULE, SIGLE, TITRE, ETAT, ANNEE FROM MODULE";
$res = mysqli_query($cxn,$requete);
while ($ligne = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td> <input type="checkbox" name="choix[]" value="'.$ligne['ID_MODULE'].'"> </td>';
    echo '<td>'.$ligne['SIGLE'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$ligne['TITRE'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.htmlentities($ligne['ETAT'], ENT_HTML5).'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$ligne['ANNEE'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: what do you mean interrogation point? `?` do you have a sample string?

Comment: it's a interrogation point in a triangle. It's the character in HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this code.

```
mysqli_set_charset($this->mysqli,"utf8");
mysqli_set_charset($cxn,"utf8");
```

Comment: The automated quality filter has flagged your answer.  Perhaps explain this a bit more?

Comment: Charset is define in HTML header. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

use the following code to see if it works:

```
echo htmlentities($ligne['ETAT'], ENT_HTML5, "UTF-8");
```

I have passed `UTF-8` as the third parameter to the `htmlentities()`;

Update:
use this function to see if it works:

```
function _decodeAccented($encodedValue, $options = array()) {
    $options += array(
        'quote'     => ENT_NOQUOTES,
        'encoding'  => 'UTF-8',
    );
    return preg_replace_callback(
        '/&\w(acute|uml|tilde);/',
        create_function(
            '$m',
            'return html_entity_decode($m[0], ' . $options['quote'] . ', "' .
            $options['encoding'] . '");'
        ),
        $encodedValue
    );
}
```

The above function is copied from comments on Official PHP.net Documentations on `htmlentities()` :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php#108222